# How do I specify EC2 instance type from cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

Is there a way to specify EC2 instance type and storage from cli ?

I've got this command with which I'm creating instance:

`docker-machine create -d amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key abc --amazonec2-secret-key xyz --amazonec2-region eu-west-2 app-prod`

this creates instance with default `micro` type and 16GB of SSD both of which I need to change.
I can change instance type from GUI but when I change storage it won't have the operating system and app installed.

Hence I'm asking how both can be specified from cli with other attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `--amazonec2-instance-type`

See: [Using Docker Machine with AWS - Scott's Weblog - The weblog of an IT pro focusing on cloud computing, Kubernetes, Linux, containers, and networking](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/03/22/using-docker-machine-with-aws/)

Comment: Yeah, the instance type I've found on my own. I haven't found how to correctly specify the storage though. It looks like I can use `--amazonec2-volume-type io1` but that requires specifying `iops` argument which I have no idea how to supply that.

Comment: Turns out it's a known issue https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3189